# How to synchronize facebook calendar, events and google calendar in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: evolution

How to synchronize facebook events, birthdays and google calendar in ubuntu.
Is there any well recognized application that can sync these things and display notifications on desktop.

Please help

Comment: Try [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/). First export your facebook events into Evolution. Then sync that particular calendar with google calendar (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-multiple-google-calendars-with-evolution-calendars).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a program called Evolution.

While it is primarily a mail client it does feature a calendar component, with syncing from google/facebook.

- Sync [Google Calendar](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleCalendarWithEvolution)
- Sync [Facebook Events](http://maxolasersquad.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/how-to-sync-your-facebook-calendar-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't a fan of Google Calendars having all your personal information there's other ways around syncronization.

**Note:** This answer outlines how to use Thunderbird Lightning and synchronize that with your Ubuntu (11-14 so far!). Personally I prefer the interface for Thunderbird rather then evolution. I hope at least this helps you somewhat answer your question.

## Install Thunderbird

1. Install Thunderbird on your machine
2. Go to Tools >> Add-ons and type "Lightning" in the search dialog
3. Then select the Available Add-ons option and install Lightning
4. Repeat the steps above but install "Automatic Export"

## Configure Thunderbird

1. Add a new Calendar (File >> New >> Calendar)

> For Facebook you need to find the iCal link on your facebook feed.

1. Add a WebCal calendar & make sure to check "Show reminders"
2. Paste in your Calendar feed
3. Repeat these steps for any other calendars that you want

## Export Calendars

This process allows us to properly export your feeds out from Thunderbird which will integrate into Ubuntu's top Calendar

1. Go to your Extensions and edit the preferences of the Automatic Export Add-on
2. Check off recurrent export and setup an output director your your files
3. Check off iCal export and which Calendars you wish to export

Integrate into Ubuntu

> As it stands Ubuntu / Ubuntu Gnome only properly integrates with Evolution

1. Start Evolution
2. Select New > Calendar
3. Check "Use an existing iCalendar" and find one of the calendars you have export
4. Uncheck "Allow Evolution to update the file"
5. Repeat for all of your calendars
6. Select Edit >> Preferences
7. Click on the Reminders tab

> You can either choose to keep reminders on (which will be initiated by THunderbird automatically) or turn them off in this interface.
>
> Close evolution (you don't need to re-open it again since the Evolution service takes care of the synchronization)
>
> You're done! Now whenever you open Thunderbird you will receive reminders from Facebook, and can view all of your events by clicking on the Date/Time in the top menu.

Comment: I'd rather use evolution. It seems to have better integration with unity, calendars and adding events to google calendars work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Fair enough this is a better solution for gnome users!